# Android requestFocus with multiple EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a problem with requestFocus and two EditTexts.

In my activity I have a LinearLayout with these EditTexts.
Here it is:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

And in my Activity:

```
 EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

When user clicks button program must check if editText2 isn't empty, and if it is empty it must be focused and keyboard must be shown. So, in my onClick method for the button I have:

```
 if(editText2.getText().toString().equals("") || editText2.getText().toString() == null){

        editText2.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
 }
```

But there is a problem. When it is empty the program focuses on editText1 (even if editText1 isn't empty, it erases all contents).

P.S. In editText1 if pressed key is Enter then editText2 must be focused. I have:

```
 editText1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                      KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {                                        
                    editText2.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);                   
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And this part works fine.

Comment: Please paste your Button onClick code also

Comment: @Kushal for this if statement I have in procedure, which i call from the onClick. But after the call of the procedure I had a requestFocus on editText1 (it must be requested on success), so this was the problem...Thanks for paying my attention :)

Comment: welcome.. It is good, your problem is solved